Gay crimes thriller movie from '80s
I remember about a movie that I saw when I was a kid, in the early 90's. In the first years after the Romanian revolution from '89, our national TV station began to produce some kind of Saturday movie marathon where I saw several movies like Jaws or Soylent Green.
So I saw this movie where a detective was investigating a series of crimes in the gay community and I think in the final scene he was face to face with the murderer, in a very dark place, both going to undress their pants so they could proceed, but the murderer took his knife and tried to kill the detective. What I remember from this movie is it was filmed in a dark theme and that I believe it promoted the idea that you shouldn't be gay, because see what happens in this community.
I suppose the movie is from '80s and the language is English, but not very sure.

I think you mean William Friedkin's Cruising from 1980 with Al Pacino.

A serial killer brutally slays and dismembers several gay men in New York's S&M and leather districts. The young police officer Steve Burns is sent undercover onto the streets as decoy for the murderer. Working almost completely isolated from his department, he has to learn and practice the complex rules and signals of this little society. While barely seeing his girlfriend Nancy anymore, the work starts changing him. 

The final showdown between the cop and the alleged killer is pretty much the scene you described and you can see it here:




This is it. I can't believe I didn't catch this minor detail that Al Pacino was in it :). Thank you
